# How do I efficiently load images into classes for processing them as efficiently as possible (Python)?

Tags: python, oop, image-processing, pipeline

The situation is as follows: we've got several cameras set up to detect and identify objects (cars) in their field of view. Snapshots taken every 5 minutes are processed by a detector network which spits out a list of detections in YOLO-format - like "license plate". These are then converted into a series of class-based objects, after which the post-processing takes place for identification (edge detection, denoising, etc.).

- My question pertains to the conversion of image detections to class-based objects, for efficient use throughout the post-processing pipeline and beyond. My colleague used ChatGPT to generate a bit of code for it which uses lazy loading principles to load images when they're needed, and to only process them when required (see the code below). The reason: some steps in post-processing apply to some segmentations, while other steps apply to other segmentations (like denoising an image taken in a low-light scenario, which is not required when lighting conditions are favorable).

My question is: the code may work, but is this a correct way of going about this? I have my doubts, but can't really argue strongly why we should not continue on this path, nor do I have a better alternative (besides putting everything into a dataframe/ database of sorts and updating that as we go instead of an object-based approach).

```
class VisualBlob:
    def __init__(self, bounding_box, mask, image, full_image_dir=None):
        self.image = image 
        self._bbox = bounding_box
        self._mask = mask 
        self._image_dir = full_image_dir 
        self._image_size = None
        self._edge_image = None

    @property
    def edge_image(self):
        if self._edge_image is None:
            self._compute_edge_image()
        return self._edge_image

    @property
    def image_dir(self):
        if self._image_dir is None:
            raise AttributeError('Accessed variable is none - image_dir not set')
        return self._image_dir
    @image_dir.setter
    def image_dir(self, new_image_dir):
        self._image_dir = new_image_dir
    @image_dir.deleter
    def image_dir(self):
        del self._image_dir

    @property
    def image_size(self):
        if self._image_size is None:
            self._compute_image_size()
        return self._image_size

    def _compute_image_size(self):
        w, h, d =self.image.shape
        self._image_size = [w,h,d]

    def _compute_edge_image(self):
        self._edge_image = cv.Canny(self.mask, 0, 1)

class LicensePlateDetection(VisualBlob):
    def __init__(self, bounding_box, mask, image, full_image_dir=None, specific_properties={}):
        super().__init__(bounding_box, mask, image, full_image_dir)
```

The goal is to process images as quickly as possible, while making sure the little PC we're running this on doesn't get too overwhelmed (especially the RAM) by the processing component, and to make sure that the images are processed correctly and completely. I understand that this isn't a typical "help I'm stuck" question, but rather a discussion question. Sources online like OpenCV's tutorials are great for understanding image processing, but offer little insight in how to handle the data before and after it is processed, especially in the case of multiple images.

Comment: I don't see any lazy loading in that code. All I see is `_edge_image` being computed when you call `edge_image()` if it hasn't been computed yet. I don't know where or why you need the "edge image", but unless you may or may not need it in various completely separate bits of code, you don't need logic like this at all.

Comment: The code I attached in my question is not representative of the complete code in the project, it was simply a code snippet with bits of the object-oriented code my colleague got from ChatGPT. The idea is to run an image processing step only once (when, and if it is needed), and keep track of the output, rather than throwing it away again until it is needed, to save both time and memory. At least, that's what my colleague intended to do. The idea being in this case, that you only need to run the Canny edge detection algorithm once. 
Legibility suffers and improvement is questionable imo.

Comment: This would save computations **if** you need the edge image again later. But it doesn’t save memory, it just wastes it: you are now saving this edge image until you discard the image object, even if you don’t need that image any more. It all depends on how you use this class, which you don’t talk about. —— Obviously the most efficient way to process an image is to compute intermediate images when you first use them and explicitly discard them when you last use them.

Comment: Thanks Cris, you summed it up nicely. I've decided to take matters into my own hand on this one and to setup an efficient pipeline with minimal memory usage and maximal efficiency in intermediate object reuse. Truth be told, it's more of a tree than a pipeline, but it works a lot more efficiently. Thanks for encouraging me to adopt this approach.